# Are the following formula 1-1 or Onto Functions?

Tags: functions, real-numbers

1) Is the function Cube Root of $\sqrt[3]{{-6x-4}}$ One to One Function if domain is all real number?

IMO, I am assuming this is an 1-1 function because well, 1) This will produce a graph of square root. So every x will have a different y value.

That's my assumption, I am not too sure if my reasoning is correct. I know i would have to solve this function to find out if its really a 1-1 function but I don't know how to do it. My best try is as follows:

$F(x_1) = \sqrt[3]{{-6x-4}}$

$F(x_2) = \sqrt[3]{{-6x-4}}$

Then I would have $F(x_1) = F(x_2)$. 
I don't know what to do after this. It would be great if someone can tell me how to move forward with or how to solve this.

B) Is the Function $g(x) = {3x^x-9}$ onto function if the domain is also all Real Numbers?

Thank you.

P.S. i don't how to write it properly. So can someone edit it please.

Comment: See the following link for a MathJax reference, which can be used to format math text in your question: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: There Mr.@Dave. I am hoping that I didn't get a downvote because of the formatting.

Comment: I certainly didn't downvote. So is your question asking if $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{-6x-4}$ is one-to-one and onto? Is the codomain of $f$ also $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Yes sir, Is part a, 1-1 funciton? and is the part b an onto function. The codomain of F is also R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We consider $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{-6x-4}$. Since $\sqrt[3]{-1}=-1$ (over the reals), we have $f(x)=-\sqrt[3]{6x+4}$. To show that $f$ is one-to-one, we need to show that
$$f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y$$
So we need to show that

> $$\sqrt[3]{6x+4}=\sqrt[3]{6y+4}\implies x=y$$

To show that $f$ is onto we have to show that, for any $y\in\Bbb R$, there exists $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=y$. So we need to show that

> $$\text{For any $y\in\Bbb R$, there exists $x\in\Bbb R$ such that }~ -\sqrt[3]{6x+4}=y$$

Comment: Thank you, Now does that mean that to show if they are truly equal, I would've to plug in a value. #2) I wanted to know if the function g(x) = {3x^x-9} is an Onto function.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in your first question: are you asking about the injective argument? To show $f$ is one-to-one (or injective), you **assume** that $f(x)=f(y)$ and you show that $x=y$, but you do not pick specific values of $x$ and $y$, you keep it general. For $g$, what is the domain and codomain of $g$? These are important things to know when talking about injectivity and surjectivity.

Comment: For the Surjectivity, The domain is all real numbers and codomain is f:R→R

Comment: The domain of $g$ is all of $\Bbb R$? This is a little dicey since even roots of negative numbers are undefined (among other things). For instance, $g(-1/2)$ is undefined over the reals. Perhaps the domain of $g$ should be $(0,\infty)$?